# Net::SMTPSyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp

i am using rails3.0.6 and ruby 1.8.7, i can easily send email from my applications development mode.But last night i saw a new error when i tried to send mail to my customers email which is polymorphic associated  with my invoice model. The error is:

```
Net::SMTPSyntaxError in InvoicesController#email_invoice 
501 < @invoice.account.accountable.email >: missing or malformed local part
```

My code for email.rb file is :

```
 def send_invoice(invoice)
   email = '@invoice.account.accountable.email'
   mail(:to => email, :from => "support@thenextwave.in", :subject=>"Invoice, check it.") 
 end
```

and in my `invoice controller` i did:

```
def email_invoice
  @company = Company.find(User.find(session[:current_user_id]))
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @invoice_line_items = @invoice.invoice_line_items
  @receipt_vouchers = @invoice.receipt_vouchers
  #email = @invoice.account.accountable.email
  Email.send_invoice(@invoice).deliver
  redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice)
  flash[:success] = 'Email has been sent successfully.'
end
```

i goggled for this error  and find that it causes due to wrong from and to email addresses or wrong SMTP settings, but my SMTP setting is ok since i can send email from my application but has problem with below line:

```
@invoice.account.accountable.email
```

any help would be thaknful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with a solution, I made mistake in `email.rb` file in my mailer :

```
def send_invoice(invoice)
  email = '@invoice.account.accountable.email'
  mail(:to => email, :from => "support@thenextwave.in", :subject=>"Invoice, check it.") 
end
```

it should be:

```
def send_invoice(invoice)
  email = invoice.account.accountable.email 
  mail(:to => email, :from => "support@thenextwave.in", :subject=>"Invoice, check it.") 
end
```

Now I can send email easily..

Comment: i made string to email address which is not accepted in mailer file, now i have updated my code

Comment: ' @invoice.account.accountable.email ' is a string literal. "#{@invoice.account.accountable.email}" would work, though there is no point in using interpolation.